# Undefined symbol “toupper” in MacPorts GCC 4.7 OS-X Mavericks 10.9 C11

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, xcode5, macports

EDIT2:

so here is an example of the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main ()
{
  int i=0;
  char str[]="Test String.\n";
  char c;
  while (str[i])
  {
    c=str[i];
    putchar (toupper(c));
    i++;
  }
  return 0;
 }
```

1) clang:

`clang++ -std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++ -lc++ main.cc -o main`

compiles fine.

2) `g++-mp-4.8 -std=c++11 main.cc -o main` gives:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "toupper(int)", referenced from:
      _main in ccWjHauc.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

3) `g++-mp-4.8 main.cc -o main` compiles!

any ideas what is wrong with the setup?

==========

Can someone help to understand what changed in Gcc/macports/os 10.9 ?

I used to have a compiling script of some third party library working in os 10.8.
Recently I updated to the new osx (10.9) and gcc 4.7 from macports stopped linking. In particular I have:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "isspace(int)", referenced from:
```

This problem is very similar to the one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576609/undefined-symbol-istype-in-macports-gcc-c11) for `istype`. 
However it seems `isspace` does not sit in libgcc++.dylib.

Any ideas what to try?

EDIT1:

indeed, 4.8 fixed the  problem with `isspace`, but another surfaced - `toupper`:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "toupper(int)", referenced from: ...
```

What is going on here?!. Is it related to the new Xcode (5.0) ?

Comment: have you included the <cctype> header?

Comment: yes, the problem is still there.

Comment: btw, to my understanding, the absence of header would lead to a compilation error as opposed to the linking error

Comment: I have the same issue in the same environment (gcc4.7 from macports on OS X 10.9). At the same time it compiles without errors using clang or gcc 4.8.

Comment: @Alexander thanks a lot for your feedback, i will try 4.8 to see if it makes a difference in my case...

Comment: My setup is OS X 10.9, Xcode 5.0.1, gcc-4.9 from Homebrew (snapshot 20131027) and I also get an undefined symbol for topper() ...

Comment: As mentioned here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576609/undefined-symbol-istype-in-macports-gcc-c11?noredirect=1#comment29168868_19576609 this is also the case for self-compiled gcc

Comment: This is clearly a bug or misconfiguration. `toupper()` is a standard C library function and is included in C++. Incidentally, `toupper()` expects either an `unsigned char` value converted to `int`, or the value `EOF`; passing a plain `char` can cause undefined behavior. `toupper(c)` should be `toupper((unsigned char)c)` (or use a C++-specific cast if you prefer). It's not strictly necessary in this case, since all the `char` values you're passing are required to be positive, but it's good practice in general. (This isn't related to the problem you're seeing.)

Comment: I'm strongly leaning towards unhandled condition in the SDK headers. I've logged a radar against the SDK, but I have no idea where it will go

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a patch in http://trac.macports.org/ticket/41033
It solved my problem.
You just have to patch the file in /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h and replace

```
#elif defined(__GNUC__) && defined(__GNUC_STDC_INLINE__)
```

by

```
#elif defined(__GNUC__) && defined(__GNUC_STDC_INLINE__) && !defined(__cplusplus)
```

Good luck.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I will wait couple of days to see if the patch is adopted.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the `ctype.h` items are declared as inline definitions, so they get expanded at compile time. When you compile without `-std=c++11`, it expands to:

```
extern inline int 
toupper(int _c) 
{ 
        return (__toupper(_c)); 
}
```

When you compile with `-std=c++11`, it expands to:

```
extern inline __attribute__((__gnu_inline__)) int 
toupper(int _c) 
{ 
        return (__toupper(_c)); 
}
```

For some reason, g++ is then choosing to ignore the perfectly good definition that is presented there.

Based on the commentary [on this invalid bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41194), it's gcc choosing to not optimize the code and looking for the definition in one of the linked libraries.

A workaround seems to be to compile with at least `-O1` optimization, which avoids the issue, but it's a real pain in the ass.

Now when we look at the differences in the #defines between non-C++11 and C++11, we see that we have an extra #define:

```
$ touch x.cc
$ g++-4.9 -dM -E x.cc | grep STD
#define __STDC_HOSTED__ 1
#define __STDC__ 1
$ g++-4.9 -std=c++11 -dM -E x.cc | grep STD
#define __STDC_HOSTED__ 1
#define __GNUC_STDC_INLINE__ 1
#define __STDC__ 1
```

and because of a piece of code in the 10.9 SDK (`usr/include/sys/cdefs.h`), all those `__DARWIN_CTYPE_TOP_inline` in `cytpe.h` get turned into `__header_inline` which get turned into `extern __inline __attribute__((__gnu_inline__))` thanks to this little bit of additional code:

```
#elif defined(__GNUC__) && defined(__GNUC_STDC_INLINE__)
# define __header_inline           extern __inline __attribute__((__gnu_inline__))
```

It looks like apple's header is trying to do the right thing, but they've not covered all their bases. There is [another issue](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55965), which mentions a similar bug.

Answer (score 0):

I've been reading up on linker errors with maverick for a few days now. The problem appears to crop up with certain tools cross linking which used to be compatible, but longer are.

Have you tried forcing all tools to use one type clang++ or llvm-g++?