# Something odd happened to C++ 11 in Mavericks?

Tags: c++, c++11, osx-mavericks, g++4.8

I am using gcc 4.8 installed via MacPorts, and old C++11 code would not compile anymore

if I use the compiler without the -std=c++11 flag, it works just fine with this test code

```
#include <cctype>

int main() {
  std::isalnum('c');
  return 0;
}


[bash] g++48 test.cpp
```

But after the Mavericks upgrade I get the following compile error:

```
[bash] g++48 -std=c++11  test.cpp 

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "isalnum(int)", referenced from:
      _main in ccvsKeqJ.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Does anyone have a clue what might cause this issue?
I appreciate any help

Comment: try (re)install xcode command line tool

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using g++? Clang supports all the GCC extensions and then some and has full C++11 support (whereas GCC's C++11 library was still missing pieces last time I checked).

Comment: This looks like a GCC installation problem. It looks like the linker can't find the standard library. Try re-installing GCC. If the MacPorts version still doesn't work, try it from another source like Homebrew.

Comment: @zneak I don't know about him, but I use GCC because clang has bugs that cause it not to compile my code. libstdc++ also has debug iterator support, which I find invaluable.

Answer (score 5):

OSX Mavericks upgrade will wipe out a number of XCode installation directories. In order to restore them, you need to reinstall the XCode command-line tools.

```
xcode-select --install
```

Then agree to the download prompt.

If this fails, you can try and install by hand from here: [OSX: Xcode Downloads](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode%20-#)

Comment: I did this before (and after the Upgrade to Mavericks), otherwise I couldn't even get the first case `g++48 test.cpp` to run. I updated macports, which took a while, and then I tried to install XCode Command Line Tools again via `xcode-select --install`, however, it said that it is currently not available on the server. I will try it again later

Comment: g++48 was installed from MacPorts, as the questions states. Xcode is not the issue.

Comment: I had a similar problem with a different missing symbol after upgrading to Mavericks, using gcc 4.8 from MacPorts, and for me, reinstalling the command line tools as explained did fix it. I can't recall precisely what the symbol was, so the difference in behaviour may be related to that.

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't relate to mis-installed osx cmdline tools, but, as clearly explained in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621831/undefined-symbol-toupper-in-macports-gcc-4-7-os-x-mavericks-10-9-c11/), to some inline-related macros changed in 10.9 SDK headers, in particular in usr/include/sys/cdefs.h.

As a quick workaround, you can leverage GCC's "fixed include" mechanisms and provide a slightly tweaked version of /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h that prevents the problem when compiling c++ code as follows:

1. Find where your installed GCC is, I'll use GCCROOT
2. mdkir $GCCROOT/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwinXXX/4.X.Y/include-fixed/sys (where darwinXXX depends on where you compiled GCC on and 4.X.Y is the GCC version you compiled)
3. Edit the just copied file ..../include-fixed/sys/cdefs.h to apply the following patch:

   ```
   @@ -216,7 +215,7 @@

   #if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L && (!defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__))
   # define __header_inline           inline
   -#elif defined(__GNUC__) && defined(__GNUC_STDC_INLINE__)
   +#elif defined(__GNUC__) && defined(__GNUC_STDC_INLINE__) && !defined (__cplusplus)
   # define __header_inline           extern __inline __attribute__((__gnu_inline__))
   #elif defined(__GNUC__)
   # define __header_inline           extern __inline
   ```

This causes, when compiling c++ code, the expansion

> __header_inline --> extern __inline

instead of

> __header_inline --> extern __inline __attribute__((__gnu_inline__))

which would apparently cause GCC not to really inline isalnum and hence leave a link-time dependency on the symbol, i.e. it would try to find it in some library, leading to the link error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you only installed the 32 bit part of gcc? Try -m32.

Comment: No, and it worked before. But you are right, looks like Mavericks moved something...

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reinstall Xcode command line tools, since yesterday using 
`xcode-select --install`
Unfortunately it doesn't work anymore, too

[image]

[image]

But then I was able to get it from
https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action

Unfortunately, reinstalling the command line tools didn't help either :(

I guess I will no go with

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++
```

until there is a official solution.

Comment: The command-line tools seem to be part of the Xcode install now -- certainly if I install Xcode 5.0.1 from the App Store I seem to automagically get all the command-line tools, when they didn't work before. Also, I didn't even need to run xcode-select... Really not sure what's going on here...